# qgis2web search attributes

Tags: qgis-plugins, attribute-table, web-mapping, qgis2web

Is it possible to query features based on attributes from the client side of qgis2web?  How can this be achieved?  I have a single data set that I want to serve over the web, while allowing users to search for locations that have specific attribute values.

Comment: Unfortunately it is difficult to "find" this post, because I miss the word qgis2web within text or as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the function "Attribute filter" within qgis2web. You could use different attributes. For example:
You have three columns:

1. countries (of the world)
2. continent/regions
3. number of inhabitants

Now you take for the attribute filter number 2 and 3.
The user can for example only show all countries in africa with more than x millions inhabitants.